# How to call the ps -u Linux/Unix command from within a C program

Tags: c, linux

The command "ps -u myusername" shows all of the currently running processes under my account name.   How do I call this in a C program?

```
x = fork(); //Create a new process fork.
if(x == 0) {
  //Then the fork was created successfully.  use the new fork to call ps.
  char *argv[2] = {"-u" ,"myusername"};
  execv("/bin/ps", argv);
}
```

Comment: Do you want to run the command, or do you want to retrieve the same data that this command retrieves? The first involves exec and possibly fork; the latter involves asking the operating system for the data.

Comment: Well, I want to display to the output of ps to the terminal, which means I would probably need to simply run the command (? not sure).

Answer (score 2):

```c
char *argv[3] = {"ps", "-l", NULL};
execv("/bin/ps", argv);
```

Remember to add NULL and the command in the end and beginning of args respectivly. (Here ps and NULL)

Answer (score -1):

http://linux.die.net/man/3/system 
http://linux.die.net/man/3/popen 
try one of these.  System executes a shell command with no way to get the output except to redirect to a file or fifo.  popen is what you want you will create a /bin/ps process and pipe all the data to your program.